# How to remove the border property, "border" in <table> does not appear when viewing elements in the browser

Tags: asp.net

How to remove the border property, "border" in  does not appear when viewing elements in the browser

https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img921/2092/InUQCG.jpg

visual studio 2017
MS SQL 2014
IIS7.0

I tried 
1.
using css and Jquery, but the border will still come out when viewing the source code of the page.

2.
I also tried the following practices
Attributes("border") = "none"
 Attributes.Remove("border")

I want to show the red box part, but he always appears
https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img921/2092/InUQCG.jpg

Thank you, everyone.

Comment: Don't post screenshots of code, post the code itself. And it should be a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue. In this case, we need not just the HTML, but the CSS as well.

Comment: That said, the output looks like it could be the table background color rather than borders. Then you should put `border-spacing:0` in the stylesheet. But this is just a guess; I can say more when you have posted the CSS.